# Studying the cryptopunks code. Why are these three conditions required?

Tags: erc-721, nft

So I recently started learning some solidity and was looking at code to make nft series like the punks.

I noticed that in their code there are always three conditions that appear to do the same thing.

```
!allPunksAssigned
punksRemainingToAssign == 0
punkIndex >= 10000
```

Why are the three of them needed? I see that one of them has to be manually activated but still, don't see the reason for the three conditions in almost every function. Shouldn't `punkIndex >= 10000` suffice? I feel like I'm missing something.

```
function getPunk(uint punkIndex) {
        if (!allPunksAssigned) throw;
        if (punksRemainingToAssign == 0) throw;
        if (punkIndexToAddress[punkIndex] != 0x0) throw;
        if (punkIndex >= 10000) throw;
        punkIndexToAddress[punkIndex] = msg.sender;
        balanceOf[msg.sender]++;
        punksRemainingToAssign--;
        Assign(msg.sender, punkIndex);
    }
```

https://github.com/larvalabs/cryptopunks/blob/master/contracts/CryptoPunksMarket.sol

Answer (score 2):

They serve different purposes

- `allPunksAssigned` A better name would be `allInitialPunksAssigned`. All operations are disabled until a set of initial punks were assigned by the contract owner.
- `punkIndex` All values between 0 and 9999 were available. A user was able to choose their favorite number in that range.
- `punksRemainingToAssign`  Counter of assigned punks.

It is possible to combine the last two if punkIndex is assigned sequentially, but they decided to allow some freedom.